# Replace extension of a filename in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Given an string with format `filename.fileextension` I want to replace the fileextension with `newextension`. How can I do it?

In java it would be

```
foo.substring(0, foo.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".newextension"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringByAppendingPathExtension` no longer works in Swift 2.0 (if you are using `String`). But it *does* still work for `NSString`. So you can do:

```
var storePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory , .UserDomainMask, true)[0]) as NSString
storePath = storePath.stringByAppendingPathExtension("model.sqlite")!
```

Answer (score 18):

A literal translation in Swift 4 would be:

```
let path2 = String(path[..<path.range(of: ".", options: .backwards)!.lowerBound] + ".newextension")
```

But Apple has been transitioning us away from `String` paths, but instead wants us to `URL` for files in our local file system.

For example, let's say we had some reference to some file in our documents directory:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)   // nowadays, you might even prefer `.applicationSupportDirectory
    .appendingPathComponent("test.png")
```

If you wanted to replace that `.png` with `.jpg`, you'd do:

```
let jpgURL = fileURL
    .deletingPathExtension()
    .appendingPathExtension("jpg")
```

---

For previous Swift versions, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27170681/3).

Comment: This does return an optional which will need to be unwrapped.

Comment: It's not required if OP initially unwrap it. Like `var foo : NSString!`

Comment: Voted up. This solution is better than mine.

Comment: swift 4.x: when using your first line of code: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') to return type 'String?'`. The second problem is how will you get filename back from `fileURL`?

Comment: really? `fileURL.path` converts "file.ext" to "/file.ext"

Comment: Ok, your answer is still incomplete. I see no info about how to replace exactly extentsion  in filename using URL. Why do I need that? For example for storing filename inside database without of any trash symbols like extra slashes

Answer (score 4):

I would totally agree with [@Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27170681/5501940) (Swift 3 Section). However, since:

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the `URL`
> structure, which bridges to the `NSURL` class.
>
> <sub>[NSURL Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl)</sub>

it should be achievable by using the [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) structure, as follows:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let destinationURL = fileURL.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("newextension")
```

So the [`deletingPathExtension()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780065-deletingpathextension) now is an instance method (instead of optional variable as declared in the NSURL):

> If the URL has an empty path (e.g., http://www.example.com), then this
> function will return the URL unchanged.

which means you don't have to handle the unwrapping of if, i.e it won't crash if the path is invalid -as mentioned in its documentation-.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C and Swift we have to find `NSRange` of `.` character to replace extension of file. Then replace sub string with new extension name. See the below code:

```
var foo : NSString!
foo = "filename.txt"

var mutableFile = NSMutableString.stringWithString(foo)

var range = mutableFile.rangeOfString(".")
var length = mutableFile.length - range.location

mutableFile .replaceCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(range.location, length), withString: ".newExtension")
println(mutableFile)

foo = NSString.stringWithString(mutableFile)
mutableFile = nil
println(foo)
```

Comment: Why fall back to the old Cocoa `NSRange`? Yes, it's our old friend, but Swift provides `Range<String.Index>` construct now. No need to fall back to the old `NS` classes here.

Comment: It's embedded in the first half of my answer, where I do literal translation of his Java. If you call `rangeOfString` on a `String` object, you get a `Range<String.Index>`. Then get the `startIndex` of that, and then use that in the `substringToIndex` function. All of this is moot, though, because scanning strings for "." is a horrible way to solve his problem. It's going to be much better to use the path/URL extension manipulation functions.

Comment: @Rob: Its not working. Have you checked it. Try this `foo = "user/documents/test.text"
        foo.stringByDeletingPathExtension.stringByAppendingPathExtension("newextension")!`

Comment: Yes, It is working now on my side too. Its a typo mistake, hard to find in Swift. BTW you are right we should go for it. Your solution is very much appreciated!